# Setting the user state when downloading asynchronously

Tags: c#, webclient

VS 2008 SP1

I am using the web clicent to download some files asynchronously.

I have 5 files to download.

However, I want to monitor each download and want to set the user state as the name of the file, so in the ProgressCompletedEvent I can check the user state to see which file has completed?

He is a short code snippet of what I am trying to do.

```
// This function will be called for each file that is going to be downloaded.
// is there a way I can set the user state so I know that the download 
// has been completed 
// for that file, in the DownloadFileCompleted Event? 
private void DownloadSingleFile()
{
    if (!wb.IsBusy)
    {        
        //  Set user state here       
        wb.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(downloadUrl), installationPath);
    }
}


void wb_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("File userstate: [ " + e.UserState + " ]");   
}

void wb_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("File userstate: [ " + e.UserState + " ]");   

    double bytesIn = double.Parse(e.BytesReceived.ToString());
    double totalBytes = double.Parse(e.TotalBytesToReceive.ToString());
    double percentage = bytesIn / totalBytes * 100;

    progressBar1.Value = int.Parse(Math.Truncate(percentage).ToString());

}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can pass any object as the *third* argument to the DownloadFileAsync() call, and you'll get it back as the userState. In your case, you could simply pass your filename.

Comment: client.UploadFileCompleted += new UploadFileCompletedEventHandler(UploadFileCallback);Client.UploadFileAsync(uri, "STOR", sourceFile,fileName);  private void UploadFileCallback(Object sender, UploadFileCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            
            MessageBox.Show(e.UserState.ToString());
         . . . 
        }

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this:

```
private void BeginDownload(
    string uriString,
    string localFile,
    Action<string, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs> onProgress,
    Action<string, AsyncCompletedEventArgs> onComplete)
{
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

    webClient.DownloadProgressChanged +=
        (object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e) =>
            onProgress(localFile, e);

    webClient.DownloadFileCompleted +=
        (object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e) =>
            onComplete(localFile, e);

    webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(uriString), localFile);
}
```

In your calling code, you could then have some code like this:

```
Action<string, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs> onProgress =
    (string localFile, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}/{2} bytes received ({3}%)",
            localFile, e.BytesReceived,
            e.TotalBytesToReceive, e.ProgressPercentage);
    };

Action<string, AsyncCompletedEventArgs> onComplete =
    (string localFile, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", localFile,
            e.Error != null ? e.Error.Message : "Completed");
    };

downloader.BeginDownload(
    @"http://url/to/file",
    @"/local/path/to/file",
    onProgress, onComplete);
```

If you don't mind about making it too reusable, you can actually just ditch the passed in functions all together and write the lambda expressions straight in your code:

```
private void BeginDownload(string uriString, string localFile)
{
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

    webClient.DownloadProgressChanged +=
        (object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e) =>
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}/{2} bytes received ({3}%)",
                localFile, e.BytesReceived,
                e.TotalBytesToReceive, e.ProgressPercentage);

    webClient.DownloadFileCompleted +=
        (object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e) =>
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", localFile,
                e.Error != null ? e.Error.Message : "Completed");

    webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(uriString), localFile);
}
```

Called twice, this will give you output someting like this

/path/to/file1: 265/265 bytes received (100%)
/path/to/file1: Completed
/path/to/file2: 2134/2134 bytes received (100%)
/path/to/file2: Completed